# create a column on a dataframe using several if conditions intervals on python

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a df and I would like to add a column 'solar_panel_area' depending on several conditions of other df column named 'floor area'.
the conditions are:

- floor area < 100 return 4
- 100 <floor area<200 return 6
- 200 <floor area<300 return 8
- else return 12

> ```
> import pandas as pd data = {'id': ['B100'], 'floor_area': [20]}
> df =pd.DataFrame(data)
> ```

I tried:

> df['solar_panel_area']= [4 if x<100 elif 6 x<200 & 8 x<300 else 12 for x in > (pair['floor_area'])]

get synthax error on elif

If I just try with 2 conditions it is correct:

```
df['solar_panel_area']= [4 if x<100 else 12 for x in(df['floor_area'])]
df
id  floor_area  solar_panel_area
0   B100    20  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fn(x):
    if x < 100:
        return 4
    if 100 < x < 200:
        return 6
    if 200 < x < 300:
        return 8
    return 12


df["solar_panel_area"] = df["floor_area"].apply(fn)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     id  floor_area  solar_panel_area
0  B100          20                 4
```

Answer (score 0):

For one liner conditions in Python, `elif` doesn't work.

There are 2 ways that you can create the new column

1. With a one-liner if-else ladder. (This is okay when you have only a certain number of conditions)

   ```py
   df["solar_panel_area"] = [
       4 if x < 100
       else 6 if x < 200
       else 8 if x < 300
       else 12
       for x in df["floor_area"]
   ]
   ```
2. Create a function and use [`df['column'].map(f)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

   ```py
   def solar_panel_area(floor_area):
       if floor_area < 100:
           return 4
       elif floor_area < 200:
           return 6
       elif floor_area<300:
           return 8
       else:
           return 12
   df["solar_panel_area"] = df["floor_area"].map(solar_panel_area)
   ```

   This works because you want to work on only a single column of data. A single column of a DataFrame is a pandas.Series. `map` is fast as it can work in parallel.
   If you need to incorporate multiple columns, you need to use `df.apply`

---